# How to create a new partition on an already encrypted hard drive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

I have already encrypted my hard drive and while installing Ubuntu 17.10 on my Lenovo Ideapad. Now I wish to create a new partition on it but Gparted is not allowing me to do so. Is there any way to create a new partition without reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -l` so we can get a better idea of your current storage set-up? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are likely better off backing up your files and reinstalling as this guide suggests, either way, this should help.

[ResizeEncryptedPartitions | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions)

Comment: I disagree. Encrypted partitions can be resized almost like regular partitions. That "almost" is the reason why none of the common graphical partition managers can deal with them though and one has to perform the steps on the command line. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster the link I provided to the Ubuntu community wiki on this topic  says "It may in fact be easier to re-install and restore your data from backup rather then attempt to resize your encrypted partition."  And then goes through the entire command line guide on how to do it. Please explain how my statement is unjustified.  and how this does not provide a valid answer to the question.

Comment: Quite the contrary: I *do* believe that this is in fact an answer according to the community standard. Otherwise I would have flagged it as "not an answer" and left a suitable comment to explain. I just disagree with its content which I expressed through my vote.